# Calculating MPG for each leg of a trip

Tags: java, javafx

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.geometry.HPos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.RadioButton;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.ToggleGroup;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MPGCalc extends Application {
    private TextField tfMiles = new TextField();
    private TextField tfGallons = new TextField();
    private TextField tfMiles1 = new TextField();
    private TextField tfGallons1 = new TextField();
    private TextField tfMiles2 = new TextField();
    private TextField tfGallons2 = new TextField();
    private TextField tfMiles3 = new TextField();
    private TextField tfGallons3 = new TextField();
    private TextField tfMiles4 = new TextField();
    private TextField tfGallons4 = new TextField();

    private Button calcMPG = new Button("Calculate");
    private TextField displayMPG = new TextField();
    private RadioButton rbStandard = new RadioButton("Standard");
    private RadioButton rbMetric = new RadioButton("Metric");
    private Label lblDistance = new Label("Miles:");
    private Label lblAmount = new Label("Gallons:");
    private Label lblDistance1 = new Label("Miles:");
    private Label lblAmount1 = new Label("Gallons:");
    private Label lblDistance2 = new Label("Miles:");
    private Label lblAmount2 = new Label("Gallons:");
    private Label lblDistance3 = new Label("Miles:");
    private Label lblAmount3 = new Label("Gallons:");
    private Label lblDistance4 = new Label("Miles:");
    private Label lblAmount4 = new Label("Gallons:");

    private Label lblMPG = new Label("MPG:");

    @Override // Override the start method in the Application class
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        // Create UI
        GridPane gridPane = new GridPane();
        gridPane.setHgap(5);
        gridPane.setVgap(5);
        gridPane.add(rbStandard, 0 ,0);
        gridPane.add(rbMetric, 1, 0);

        gridPane.add(lblDistance, 0, 1);
        gridPane.add(tfMiles, 1, 1);
        gridPane.add(lblAmount, 0, 2);
        gridPane.add(tfGallons, 1, 2);

        gridPane.add(lblDistance1, 0, 3);
        gridPane.add(tfMiles1, 1, 3);
        gridPane.add(lblAmount1, 0, 4);
        gridPane.add(tfGallons1, 1, 4);

        gridPane.add(lblDistance2, 0, 5);
        gridPane.add(tfMiles2, 1, 5);
        gridPane.add(lblAmount2, 0, 6);
        gridPane.add(tfGallons2, 1, 6);

        gridPane.add(lblDistance3, 0, 7);
        gridPane.add(tfMiles3, 1, 7);
        gridPane.add(lblAmount3, 0, 8);
        gridPane.add(tfGallons3, 1, 8);

        gridPane.add(lblDistance4, 0, 9);
        gridPane.add(tfMiles4, 1, 9);
        gridPane.add(lblAmount4, 0, 10);
        gridPane.add(tfGallons4, 1, 10);

        gridPane.add(calcMPG, 0, 11);
        gridPane.add(displayMPG, 1, 12);
        gridPane.add(lblMPG, 0, 12);


        // Set properties for UI
        gridPane.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        tfMiles.setAlignment(Pos.BOTTOM_RIGHT);
        tfGallons.setAlignment(Pos.BOTTOM_RIGHT);
        calcMPG.setAlignment(Pos.BOTTOM_RIGHT);
        displayMPG.setAlignment(Pos.BOTTOM_RIGHT);
        displayMPG.setEditable(false);      
        ToggleGroup group = new ToggleGroup();
        rbStandard.setToggleGroup(group);
        rbMetric.setToggleGroup(group);


        // Process events
        calcMPG.setOnAction(e -> calculateMPG());

                rbStandard.setOnAction(e -> rbStandard());

                rbMetric.setOnAction(e -> rbMetric());

        // Create a scene and place it in the stage
        Scene scene = new Scene(gridPane, 400, 250);
        primaryStage.setTitle("MPG Calculator"); // Set title
        primaryStage.setScene(scene); // Place the scene in the stage
        primaryStage.show(); // Display the stage
                rbStandard.setSelected(true);
    }

    private void calculateMPG() {
            double gallons = Double.parseDouble(tfGallons.getText());
            double miles = Double.parseDouble(tfMiles.getText());

            double mpg = miles / gallons;

            displayMPG.setText(String.format("%.2f", mpg));

    }

        private void rbStandard(){

            lblDistance.setText("Miles:");
            lblAmount.setText("Gallons:");        
            lblMPG.setText("MPG:");

            double liters = Double.parseDouble(tfGallons.getText());
            double kilometers =  Double.parseDouble(tfMiles.getText());
            double kml = Double.parseDouble(tfMiles.getText());

            double gallons  = liters / 3.785411784;
            double miles = kilometers * 1.6;
            double mpg = miles / liters;

            tfGallons.setText(String.format("%.2f", gallons));
            tfMiles.setText(String.format("%.2f", miles));
            displayMPG.setText(String.format("%.2f", mpg));



        }


        private void rbMetric(){

            lblDistance.setText("Kilometers:");
            lblAmount.setText("Liters:");        
            lblMPG.setText("KM/L:");

            double gallons = Double.parseDouble(tfGallons.getText());
            double miles = Double.parseDouble(tfMiles.getText());
            double mpg = Double.parseDouble(tfMiles.getText());

            double liters = gallons * 3.785411784;
            double kilometers = miles/1.6;
            double kml = miles / liters;

            tfGallons.setText(String.format("@%.2f", gallons));
            tfMiles.setText(String.format("@%.2f", miles));
            displayMPG.setText(String.format("@%.2f", mpg));

        }

    /**
     * The main method is only needed for the IDE with limited
     * JavaFX support. Not needed for running from the command line.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

This started out as just a MPG calculator but now I am trying to make it calculate the MPG for up to 5 stops in a trip, and then at the end of the 5 stops, calculate the final MPG for the trip.

Right now it will calculate the MPG for the first stop, but afterwards it leaves out the inputs for the text fields 1-4.

I tried setting the getText in the calculateMPG to the correct text fields but it still didn't change the output. I also thought about just making several methods for each leg but I wasn't sure if there was a more efficient way to do it.

Comment: Use `ArrayList` or similar..

Comment: Your code explicitly handles only the first couple of fields `tfGallons` and `tfMiles`. What are you surprised about? You're not doing anything with the rest.

Comment: I know that I am only calling the tfGallons and tfMiles, because I am unsure of how to add the other four and add them together to get the total MPG from each stop. @user1803551

Comment: There are all sorts of clever solutions, but why not start with reading the other fields just like you are doing now with the first 2, than add the numbers. Is the math troubling you?

Comment: I read in all 5 fields, I am just unsure of the math to compute all the trips.

Comment: You can add all the miles, then add all the gallons, then divide.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a little bit better of a solution everyone feel free to edit to make more efficient if you want

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MPGCalc extends Application {

    private Button calcMPG = new Button("Calculate");
    private TextField displayMPG = new TextField();
    private RadioButton rbStandard = new RadioButton("Standard");
    private RadioButton rbMetric = new RadioButton("Metric");

    private Label[] distanceLabels = new Label[5];
    private Label[] amountLabels = new Label[5];

    private TextField[] distanceTextFields = new TextField[5];
    private TextField[] amountTextFields = new TextField[5];

    private Label lblMPG = new Label("MPG:");

    @Override // Override the start method in the Application class
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        createLists();

        // Create UI
        GridPane gridPane = new GridPane();
        gridPane.setHgap(5);
        gridPane.setVgap(5);

        gridPane.add(rbStandard, 0 ,0);
        gridPane.add(rbMetric, 1, 0);

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            if(i%2==0) {
                gridPane.add(distanceLabels[i / 2], 0, i+1);
                gridPane.add(distanceTextFields[i / 2], 1, i+1);
            }
            else {
                gridPane.add(amountLabels[i / 2], 0, i+1);
                gridPane.add(amountTextFields[i / 2], 1, i+1);
            }
        }

        gridPane.add(calcMPG, 0, 11);
        gridPane.add(displayMPG, 1, 12);
        gridPane.add(lblMPG, 0, 12);


        // Set properties for UI
        gridPane.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        calcMPG.setAlignment(Pos.BOTTOM_RIGHT);
        for (int i = 0; i < distanceLabels.length; i++) {
            distanceLabels[i].setAlignment(Pos.BOTTOM_RIGHT);
            distanceTextFields[i].setAlignment(Pos.BOTTOM_RIGHT);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < amountLabels.length; i++) {
            amountLabels[i].setAlignment(Pos.BOTTOM_RIGHT);
            amountTextFields[i].setAlignment(Pos.BOTTOM_RIGHT);
        }
        displayMPG.setAlignment(Pos.BOTTOM_RIGHT);
        displayMPG.setEditable(false);
        ToggleGroup group = new ToggleGroup();
        rbStandard.setToggleGroup(group);
        rbMetric.setToggleGroup(group);


        // Process events
        calcMPG.setOnAction(e -> calculateMPG());

        rbStandard.setOnAction(e -> rbStandard());

        rbMetric.setOnAction(e -> rbMetric());

        // Create a scene and place it in the stage
        Scene scene = new Scene(gridPane, 400, 425);
        primaryStage.setTitle("MPG Calculator"); // Set title
        primaryStage.setScene(scene); // Place the scene in the stage
        primaryStage.show(); // Display the stage
        rbStandard.setSelected(true);
    }

    private void createLists(){
        for (int i = 0; i < distanceLabels.length; i++) {
            distanceLabels[i] = new Label("Miles");
            distanceTextFields[i] = new TextField("");
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < amountLabels.length; i++) {
            amountLabels[i] = new Label("Gallons:");
            amountTextFields[i] = new TextField("");
        }
    }

    private void setDistanceLabel(String labelName){
        for (Label distanceLabel : distanceLabels)
            distanceLabel.setText(labelName);
    }

    private void setAmountLabels(String labelName){
        for (Label amountLabel : amountLabels)
            amountLabel.setText(labelName);
    }

    private void calculateMPG() {
        double totalTrip = 0;
        for (TextField distanceTextField : distanceTextFields)
            if (distanceTextField != null && !distanceTextField.getText().equals(""))
                totalTrip = totalTrip + Double.parseDouble(distanceTextField.getText());

        double totalAmount = 0;
        for (TextField amountTextField : amountTextFields) {
            if (amountTextField != null && !amountTextField.getText().equals(""))
                totalAmount = totalAmount +Double.parseDouble(amountTextField.getText());
        }

        displayMPG.setText(String.valueOf(totalTrip/totalAmount));
    }

    private void rbStandard(){
        setDistanceLabel("Miles");
        setAmountLabels("Gallons:");
        lblMPG.setText("MPG:");
    }


    private void rbMetric(){
        setDistanceLabel("Kilometers:");
        setAmountLabels("Liters:");
        lblMPG.setText("KM/L:");
    }

    /**
     * The main method is only needed for the IDE with limited
     * JavaFX support. Not needed for running from the command line.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```